# The type new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method

Tags: java, android, eclipse, inheritance

I just started programming, but I don't really get the method `OnCompletionListener()`. I already google the error I have: "The type new `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){}` must implement the inherited abstract method `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.onCompletion(MediaPlayer)"` I tried to change some things in my code, but it still doesn't work. Can anyone tell me exactly what I need to change in my code? Thanks in advance.

So I just started programming, but I don't really get the method `OnClickListener`. I already google the error I have: "The type new `View.OnClickListener(){}` must implement the inherited abstract method `View.OnClickListener.OnClick(View)"` and I tried to change some things in my code, but it still doesn't work. Can anyone tell me exactly what I need to change in my code? Thanks.

MainMenuScreen.java:

```
package com.example.memutarfileaudio;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

class memutarfileaudio extends Activity{

   ImageButton putar;
   TextView keterangan;
   MediaPlayer mp;
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate (Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate (SavedInstanceState);
       setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);

       keterangan=(TextView) findViewById (R.id.ket);
       keterangan.setText ("Silakan klik tombol play");

       putar=(ImageButton) findViewById (R.id.putarMusik);
       putar.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick (View arg0) {
               putar.setEnabled (false);
               keterangan.setText ("Tombol play tidak aktif");
                   go();
           }
       });
   }
   public void go() {
   mp=MediaPlayer.create(memutarfileaudio.this, R.raw.kempot);
          try {
              mp.prepare();
          } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } 
          mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener (new OnCompletionListener() {
          public void OnCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
              putar.setEnabled(true);
              keterangan.setText ("Silakan klik tombol play");
          }
   });
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java is case-sensitive and the method needs to start with a lowercase `o`, so you should change it to:

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener (new OnCompletionListener() {
          public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
```